# Force bins with zero-height in matplotlib bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following script:

```
import pylab
counts = [0,0,0,125,56,0,0,0,34,77,123,0,0,0]
pylab.bar(*zip(*enumerate(counts)), align='center')
pylab.show()
```

When I run this I get the following image.
[image: barchart]

As you can see the 0-height bins at the edges of the plot are not plotted. However, I want them indeed to be plotted. What can I do to achieve this?

I know that I can set the x_lim of the axes (`Axes.set_xlim`). If no other option exists, what approach takes most elegantly into account the width of the bars?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean... Do you want to plot the bars with 0 height as some other height, change the y-limits of the bars so that 0 is not at the bottom, or change the x-limits of the graph?

Comment: @JoeKington I acknowledge that one can not draw a rectangle with zero height. But I want the x-Axis not to automatically strip off zero bin values at the edges of my input data for the plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found another solution that may be working more reliably than `set_xlim`:

```
import pylab
counts = [0,0,0,125,56,0,0,0,34,77,123,0,0,0]
# add a epsilon to counts to force bins to be plotted
epsilon = 1e-7
counts = [x+epsilon for x in counts]
pylab.bar(*zip(*enumerate(counts)), align='center')
pylab.show()
```

[image: barchart]

Comment: On a side note, you could just change the zero bins. E.g. `counts = np.array([0,125,...,0], dtype=np.float)` and then `counts[counts == 0] = 1e-7`.  Your approach of setting 0 to some other (small) value is probably the cleanest way, actually.

Comment: @JoeKington Unfortunately you can still see the edge lines of the patches (if you are really picky).

Answer (score 6):

One way would be something similar to the following:

```
import pylab
counts = [0,0,0,125,56,0,0,0,34,77,123,0,0,0]
artists = pylab.bar(*zip(*enumerate(counts)), align='center')

lefts = [item.get_x() for item in artists]
rights = [item.get_x() + item.get_width() for item in artists]
pylab.xlim([min(lefts), max(rights)])

pylab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: apparantly the 13 is still stripped off?